# How can I embed complex types into wsdl definition?

Tags: wcf, delphi, xsd, wsdl

WCF generates complex types as external xsd files. How can I embed these definitions into wsdl? Because Delphi WSDL importer cannot import the complex types in the xsd files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WSDL has a section call `<wsdl:types>` which you can use for your XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
    ....
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="......">
           [here you can either import an XSD from a external file,
            or add your XML schema directly]
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

There are at least three WCF extensions that I'm aware of which will do that for you:

- [Christian Weyer: Improving WCF Interoperability: Flattening your WSDL](http://blogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/archive/2007/05/10/414840.aspx)
- [Flatten your WSDL with this Custom ServiceHost for WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/23/flatten-your-wsdl-with-this-custom-servicehost-for-wcf.aspx) (implemented as a separate, custom ServiceHost class)
- [WCFExtras on Codeplex](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/)

Marc